# How to retrieve newsfeeds posted by FB apps using FB graph api?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I've been sarching for hours on FB graph api docs and google but couldn't find a solution. Let me explain my question. Using the FB graph API, we are able to retrieve user's newsfeeds, but how do we retrieve user's newsfeeds that are posted by FB apps, such as game scores/achievements? I know that it's possible to retrieve user's newsfeeds created by a specific app by adding filter=app_[app_id], but is there a way to filter newsfeeds that are created by any apps?

Currently what I do is that, if a newsfeed contains a link that links to app.facebook.com, I assume it's posted by an FB app. I'm not sure if this assumption is safe and is there a better way to achieve my goal?

P.S. I use php SDK so a php solution is highly appreciated. Solutions using other SDK are also appreciated. I'll try to make a conversion by myself.

Thanks in advance,

Kaze

Answer (score 0):

> Currently what I do is that, if a newsfeed contains a link that links to app.facebook.com, I assume it's posted by an FB app.

Posts in /me/feed that have been made by/using an app should have a property "application" set, which contains the app name, namespace and id – so by just looking for that you should be able to determine if it was posted by an app or manually.